# FancyBox opens too low on the page

Tags: scroll, fancybox, position, css-position

I'm using FancyBox on my page, and occasionally (but not always), the lightbox opens too far down the page, getting cut off at the bottom and making you scroll down to view the rest of it. Normally, it'll be positioned in the dead center of the page.

I'm setting its position to `fixed` in the `onStart` method when I call it, and most of the time it *does* open in the center like it's supposed to - so I don't know what's causing it to get thrown off, but only sometimes.

The site is [Raditaz.com](http://www.raditaz.com): play an existing station (or create your own - you don't need an account) and then click the album art in the middle to open the lightbox.

Any leads on this would be appreciated - thanks!

EDIT: A few updates...

- If I resize the window once the FancyBox is opened, it'll reposition itself correctly in the center (but only until I close and reopen it again, at which point it will be shifted too low again)
- The incorrect positioning seems to occur most frequently in WebKit browsers (Safari and Chrome)

EDIT 2: I should have pointed out that the version of Fancybox we're using is 1.3.4, not the newer 2.0. Our version of jQuery is 1.6.4. It's possible that using Fancybox 2.0 would solve the problem, but (I think) that requires jQuery 1.7, which is incompatible with some of the other plugins we're using. So I'd prefer a fix that works with Fancybox 1.3.4.

Comment: can't help, got this message `We're sorry, but Raditaz is currently unavailable in your country`

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention" (from people in the US)  :P

Comment: @daGUY - I'm not able to replicate your problem :( It seems to position just fine. I'm on Chrome 16 on Ubuntu 10.04. What is a problem is all the skipping of the Ozzy song I'm listening to. I'm not sure if it's my computer (a 2003 Dell Server ;) ) or the stream. Will check your site out at work on a faster computer as it's cool to have another alternative music site :)

Comment: **EDIT:** Please update Fancybox to v2.0 which is compatible with jQuery v1.6.4 that you are using. The Fancybox v2.0 source file says jQuery v1.6.0 is the minimum required version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I visited your webpage and was able to **reproduce the issue repeatedly** once I found the bug, and that was using Firefox.

To begin, here is a reference photo of the issue:
[image]

Note in the above image **Fancybox** is not centered in the browser and the top of the artists photo is just under the **Totem Ticker Plugin** you are using.

The next reference photo is a close-up of the red framed section that shows the **Totem Ticker** is overlaying objects:
[image]

These **two issues** are related. To reproduce the **FancyBox opens too low on the page** issue you will need to click on a **mini-artist image** next to the centered larger image that has played a few songs ago, and while the Totem Ticker Plugin is ***in the process*** of animating.

These reference images shows what happens when the timing is right. If timing is not right or the slider is using a image in the cache that hasn't cleared yet, you will need to try again. Usually you will start to see the Totem Ticker overlap other objects.

Now that the bug has been found, here is a **working solution** to take care of it. You will use callbacks in the Fancybox plugin to turn off the Totem Ticker when Fancybox is about to animate, and turn back on the Totem Ticker when Fancybox closes.

Because the Totem Ticker does not have any API to interface with it, you must use the process outlined by that plugin to use start and stop options via an anchored button. The good news is you don't need to have a text-link associated with it thus making it not seen. Here's the code to review:

```
jQuery Totem Ticker jQuery Before:

    $('#trending ul').totemticker({
        direction: 'up',
        interval: 5000,
        mousestop: true,
        row_height: '74px'
    });


jQuery Totem Ticker jQuery After:

    $('#trending ul').totemticker({
        direction: 'up',
        interval: 5000,
        mousestop: true,
        row_height: '74px',
        start: '#totemStart',
        stop: '#totemStop'
    });



jQuery Totem Ticker HTML Before:

        <div id="trending" class="column aside">
            <div class="section title"><span>Top Trending Stations</span></div>
            <div class="fadeout"></div>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>


jQuery Totem Ticker HTML After:

        <div id="trending" class="column aside">
            <div class="section title"><span>Top Trending Stations</span></div>
            <div class="fadeout"></div>
            <ul></ul>
            <a id="totemStart" href="#"></a>
            <a id="totemStop" href="#"></a>
        </div>





Imported raditaz.min.build File Before:

    $("#album-art-anchor").fancybox({
        scrolling: "auto",
        autoscale: true,
        autoDimensions: true,
        width: 455,
        height: 495,
        titlePosition: "outside",
        onStart: function () {
            $("#fancybox-overlay").css({
                position: "fixed",
                overflow: "scroll"
            });
        },
        onClosed: onTrackLightboxClosed
    });


Imported raditaz.min.build File After:

    $("#album-art-anchor").fancybox({
        scrolling: "auto",
        autoscale: true,
        autoDimensions: true,
        width: 455,
        height: 495,
        titlePosition: "outside",
        onStart: function () {
            $("#fancybox-overlay").css({
                position: "fixed",
                overflow: "scroll"
            });
        },
        onClosed: onTrackLightboxClosed,

        // Below is added above is original.
        //
        beforeShow: function(){
            $('#totemStop').click();
        },
        afterClose: function(){
            $('#totemStart').click();
        },
        onComplete: function(){
           $.fancybox.center;
        }
    });
```

The `onComplete` fires right after the content has shown, and the function uses Fancybox API to center the contents in the viewport... but IMHO that's now not necessary since we are taking care of the issue causing it. I included that to be sure since I can not reproduced a failing condition on my end, but the two plugins were tested together to ensure this answer helps to address your issue.

To be sure, you can always run **$.fancybox.center;** in a setTimeout so that it fires after Fancybox has stabilized:

```
setTimeout("$.fancybox.center;", 1000);
```

`onStart` use of `overflow: "scroll"` causes an empty vertical bar on the right side for Chrome.

On a side note since the site is in development, besides Firefox with Firebug plugin, I used [HTML Validator Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/) for Firefox. It highlights errors when viewing the source html page and provides solutions. For example, on homepage line 389 is unclosed Class Name. On line 587/589 is duplicate ID's. Some errors aren't errors, like when plugins inject their unique tags into the markup.

**EDIT:** Per your recent SO Question Edit: Please update Fancybox to v2.0 which is compatible with jQuery v1.6.4 that you are using. The Fancybox v2.0 source file says jQuery v1.6.0 is the minimum required version.

If anything was unclear please let me know and I will try to explain differently. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! However: Totem Ticker can't be the cause, because it was only added to the site on May 25 (I can confirm by checking my history in git), but this problem has been occurring for much longer (note that I posted the original question on May 8, and it started even before then). Maybe it's simply the addition of calling `$.fancybox.center` after the FancyBox shows that's fixing it?

Comment: `$.fancybox.center` alone didn't help, so I tried your exact solution and I'm still seeing the problem in Chrome consistently.

Comment: It wasn't so much Totem Ticker than it being another jQuery object with animation that is going on. However, if you don't see issues with the Totem objects crashing nor can duplicate the failure as I described then something is the matter. Only when the Totem Ticker is no animation is their no issue with centering of Fancybox while using your test link. I'll post back if I see something else.

Comment: Update to answer to try setTimeout, please try.

Comment: I just looked at your website on `Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m` and still see the extra vertical bar that is empty. In `onStart`, remove `overflow` option or use something other than `scroll` to fix vertical bar issue which can contribute to incorrect vertical positioning of Fancybox.

Comment: I actually (independently) tried upgrading to fancyBox 2 and that seems to have fixed the problem! I didn't attempt this earlier because I assumed it required jQuery 1.7, which isn't compatible with some of the other plugins I'm using. Fortunately, it works fine with 1.6.4.

Comment: I tested their downloadable v2.0 Demo with jQuery 1.6.4 with no issues seen as mentioned in my answer. The creditable source information I used for my SO Answer come from the Fancybox source file directly: jquery.fancybox.js  That said, it's 100% safe to realize this is the solution, not that it seems to be.

Comment: @daGUY, Thank you for the upvote. Please note I did mention to use Fancybox v2.0 with jQuery v1.64 in my SO Answer 18 minutes prior to your independent tests and posted comment. Is their a reason my answer is not accepted as the correct answer?

Comment: @attronics: just that I wanted to really confirm that fancyBox 2.0 fixed the problem, which it seems like it did. Answer accepted and bounty awarded to you :-)

Comment: @daGUY, Thank you. Please consider the Fancybox beforeShow and afterClose to address issue of crashing Totem Ticker objects but equally as important Fancybox not centering correctly per my answer. That said, it's a coincidence Fancybox has a 2nd reason not to center correctly. It's easily reproduced in Firefox as described. My test environment used Totem Ticker(your .js downloaded version) with official demo markup inside Fancybox v2 demo markup. To avoid unforeseen 3rd reason for Fancybox not to center correctly, pause other jQuery animations before Fancybox animates via beforeShow method.

Comment: If using Fancybox 2.x, use `$fancybox.reposition()` instead of `$fancybox.center()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you site either. But you can probably delete all fancbox stuff, download it again and install it. That will remove problems that are in fancybox.

Otherwise, check if you have some code that is not meant to target fancybox, but does anyway.

But first of all, upgrade to a newer jquery. You are currently using 1.6. Now is 1.7.2 available. They have fixed some bugs in the new one.

Comment: Hello Camhänget. The reason why you see older version of jQuery in use is because not all plugin's work with newer versions of jQuery. jQuery v1.6.4 is very common for many sites, but it's the plugin's requirements that you must consider for all scripts involved.

Comment: Upgrading jQuery could potentially cause more problems than it solves. We use many plugins across the site and not all of them are compatible with the latest version, so "just update jQuery" ends up being a lot more complex than it sounds.

Comment: Well, how could I possibly know that? That was just an idea I had.  It sometimes solves weird problems